# Why does g++ generate huge error log?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++

Somewhere I saw this malformed C++ program could make g++ generate a huge error log:

```
int main()
{
    struct x struct z<x(x(x(x(x(x(x(y,x(y><y*,x(y*w>v<y*,w,x{};
    return 0;
}
```

By repeating `(x` many times, the error log can grow into >1GB. So this program can be used to drain a victim's system resources. While this problem can be remedied by `--fmax-error`, I'm curious what is happening inside g++ during its compilation that makes it spit such a log.

Comment: You are asking about a language's internal logging function. This is not a security question even though you are concerned about a potential DoS implication.

Comment: Probably best suited for gcc dev mailing list.

Comment: What does the content of the log look like?

Comment: Unless the "victim" is some kind of online compilation service, it's hard to see how this could serve as an attack. Most people don't frequently compile random source code. In what context do you worry about this?

Comment: @rici You just got it. It's indeed online compilation service.

Comment: @cyker: i think expanding error logs are the least of your problems, then. Template expansion can take enormous resources, both time and memory. Even without c++, you can create macros with exponential expansions. You would definitely need to run the compiler inside a resource limited sandbox.

Comment: @rici Yes it's true that the compiler should run in a sandbox. But manually crafting a really safe sandbox is non-trivial. Using a VM or LXC looks better. For this question, well, I just found the example very interesting and would like to understand what the g++ compiler is doing with the source.

Comment: @Cyker: at a guess, it's failed error recovery in the parser. Probably it's doing some kind of backtracking parse after a syntax error is found, in the hopes that it can find some alternative interpretation which makes sense. Clang doesn't fall into that trap. But my point was that there are *valid* short programs whose compilation takes time exponential in the input size. If you want to worry about a DoS attack, you'd need to worry about those, and that means resource-limiting the compile environment. That will take care of exponential error logs, too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really answer *what particular* set of things is going on, such that the errors are innumerable, but remember that C++ has possibly *the most complex* grammar known to man.

Part of the job of a compiler is informing the user **what** is wrong with a particular input, that it isn't valid (or in the case of warnings, good) C++.

You can get exponential growth of error messages when you recursively have an ambiguity, as the compiler will inform you of the set of things that it *could* mean. Suppose `?` could mean `A` or `B`, `???` could be any of `AAA`, `AAB`, `ABA`, `ABB`, `BAA`, `BAB`, `BBA`, or `BBB`.

The compiler only knows that the 100000000th near-repetition isn't important to *you* when you tell it so with `--fmax-error`.

Comment: To be fair, as a QoI issue, I'd expect a default value for `--fmax-error` to be something a little more reasonable. I thought that it was. Still, I'm not seeing what sort of "victimhood" could be achieved with this